# Where can I find schematics of rockets with their stage sizes?

Tags: design

I want to recreate real rockets inside a space sim game called KSP, but for that I need to know what sizes those rockets have ( diameter, height, etc ), not just in general, but each of their stages specifically.

For example, I found on the official [ULA website](https://www.ulalaunch.com/rockets/delta-iv) that the fairing of the rocket Delta V is 5 m in diameter and 15.992 m in height, but I can't find anything about the first or second stage.

Anyone know where I could find this info? I only need sizes.

EDIT:

To clarify, I want stage height and diameters, for example, how tall is the first stage of the Atlas V or Delta IV? I have searched on Wiki but it only gives me the total height of the rockets in question.

EDIT 2:

I looked again and I did find the sizes for the stages of Atlas V on Wiki, but not Delta IV. Wikipedia is inconsistent. What a shocker. Any place with consistent info?

Comment: I don't know if there is anything helpful here, but check answers to the meta question [Resources and references on the topic of space exploration](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/249/12102)

Answer (score 1):

There's no single complete-and-consistent site. Wikipedia is a pretty good resource in my experience (and you should contribute to it when you find it deficient), but here are a few others:

[Spaceflight101](http://spaceflight101.com/spacerockets/) has a good library of current launchers, with quite a bit of information about each of their stages, but no historical data.

[Astronautix aka Encyclopedia Astronautica](http://www.astronautix.com/s/search.html) has a wealth of historical information, but isn't very well organized or consistent in the data provided.

[Gunter's Space Page](https://space.skyrocket.de) has more information on individual flights, but less specification info on the launchers.

(Are you using RSS/RO, or stock KSP?)

Comment: Astronautix ... isn't well organised, consitent, or accurate

Comment: I'm using RSS but not RO